# Why is Maven using test resources in a production build?

Tags: java, maven-2, spring-mvc

In a maven project I have several modules which only have a persitence.xml for unit-tests in

```
src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml
```

If I build the project with 'package' the (unit-test) persistence.xml is copied into the jar file.

The created artifact (jar) is not supposed to have any persistence.xml because it is already contained in a war file which includes several modules.

The poms are very small and have no plugins configured, everything should be the default behaviour.

- What am I doing wrong?
- Is there any documentation available which explains this effect?

Comment: Do you happen to be using an IDE? I've had Eclipse do something similar. The Eclipse output folder for src/test/resources was set to the default (target/classes), so whenever Eclipse compiled the project, it would copy the files from src/test/resources to target/classes. On `mvn package`, Maven would happily copy everything from target/classes into the jar.

Comment: @ig0774 thanks I will check this on monday, you should have posted this as an answer ;-)

Comment: @ig0774 You were right, the Eclipse compile destination directory was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run Maven with the debug flag, i.e. `mvn -X ...` do you see any messages indicating that files from `src/test` are being copied? If so, you might want to check the Maven goal that performs this activity.

Also, you might want to check the contents of the `target/classes` and `target/test-classes` directories of the project/module after the Maven build. Assuming that the module has a packaging of jar, the [`maven-jar-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) merely picks up the contents of the project's output directory, i.e. `target/classes` or `${project.build.outputDirectory}` while carefully avoiding the project's test output directory, i.e. `target/test-classes` or `${project.build.testOutputDirectory}`. This should also be evident from the output of `mvn -X ...`.

Finally, you might want to check the contents of your local Maven repository for the jar file created. It might so happen that your `maven-war-plugin` used to create the WAR file, 
might be picking an older and incorrect version of the JAR that has the test persistence bundled in it, from the local repository.